# Get column information based on other column

Tags: php, mysql

I have this:

```
//Verification status 
$query = "SELECT name,verified FROM users";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
$stmt->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$result2=$stmt->get_result();
$posterInfo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
```

The query responds something like:

[image]

I want to pull out the information based on the left from (name) and return verified status. This is what I tried:

```
$posterInfo['dx_dt']
```

That should return `y`. If I used:

```
$posterInfo['NotCheshire']
```

It should return `n`.

However, that doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: If I understand this correctly - you should have an array called `$posterInfo` of the form `array('name' => {name}, 'verified' => {verified})` ... I'm not sure what `$row` is but I'm guessing you're attempting to find something like `$posterInfo['agentnola']` with `$posterInfo[$row['poster']]` which isn't going to work - the "name" isn't an index in that array. You'll probably need to loop the array to find where `$posterInfo['name'] == $row['poster']` and get the corresponding `verified` status (or use an iteration/callback function)

Comment: @CD001 I updated my post to make it more clear, will your idea work with what I meant? I think it should, but I want to make sure (I'm not able to edit my website right now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a WHERE clause to the SELECT query.

```
$query = "SELECT name,verified FROM users WHERE name = \"agentnola\"";
```

Or as your code suggests:

```
$query = "SELECT name,verified FROM users WHERE name = \"".$ row ["poster"]."\"";
```

**Edit**
You should create an associative array using PHP

```
$posterInfo = array ();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
  $posterInfo[$row["name"]] = $row["verified"];
}
```

Comment: I did that the first time however I don't want to query the database each post because there's a few hundred that run each time the page is loaded.

Comment: @Chipperyman You should fix it with PHP as shown in the edited post